# Java infix calculator logic

Tags: java, logic, calculator

I am having trouble figuring out the logic for an infix calculator that is dynamic. I am able to accommodate string values with 5 elements, such as "1 + 1", but I cannot compute strings with more than 5 elements (ie: "1 + 2 + 3 + 4").

This is my process

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

public static int calculate(String input)
    { 
        int lhs = 0;
        int rhs = 0;
        int total = 0;
        char operation = ' ';

```
    int intOne, intTwo;

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);

    /*
     * this block is chosen if there are no operations
     */

    // block of if statement code for inputs less than or equal to
    // 5 characters.

        /*
         * this block generates the correct number if there is more than
         * one operator in the equation.
         */

    }else if(input.length() > 5){
        int firstValue = 0;
        int latterValue = 0;

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            /*
             * method that assigns the left and right sides
             */

            //assigns values to the first equation
            int firstToken = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            String opToken = st.nextToken();
            int latterToken = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            //returns a value for the first equation
            firstValue = assignSides(firstToken, opToken, latterToken);

            // takes in the next operator
            if(st.nextToken().equals("+")){
                operation = '+';
            }else if(st.nextToken().equals("-")){
                operation = '-';
            }else if(st.nextToken().equals("*")){
                operation = '*';
            }else if(st.nextToken().equals("/")){
                operation = '/';
            }

            // assigns values to the latter equation
            firstToken = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            opToken = st.nextToken();
            latterToken = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            //returns a value for the latter equation
            latterValue = assignSides(firstToken, opToken, latterToken);

            /*
             * decides how to add the two equations
             */
            switch(operation){
            case '+': total = firstValue + latterValue;
            break;
            case '-': total = firstValue - latterValue;
            break;
            case '*': total = firstValue * latterValue;
            break;
            case '/': total = firstValue / latterValue;
            break;
            default: System.out.println("cannot compute");
            break;
            }

            if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                //makes the total the first value
                total = firstValue; 

                if(st.nextToken().equals("+")){
                    operation = '+';
                }else if(st.nextToken().equals("-")){
                    operation = '-';
                }else if(st.nextToken().equals("*")){
                    operation = '*';
                }else if(st.nextToken().equals("/")){
                    operation = '/';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}

public static int assignSides(int firstToken, String opToken, int latterToken)
{
    int lhs=0;
    int rhs = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    char operation = ' ';

    /*
     * converts the string into a character
     */
    if(opToken.equals("+")){
        operation = '+';
    }else if(opToken.equals("-")){
        operation = '-';
    }else if(opToken.equals("*")){
        operation = '*';
    }else if(opToken.equals("/")){
        operation = '/';
    }

    rhs = latterToken;

    /*
     * interprates the character as a function
     */
    switch(operation){
    case '+': sum = lhs + rhs;
    break;
    case '-': sum = lhs - rhs;
    break;
    case '*': sum = lhs * rhs;
    break;
    case '/': sum = lhs / rhs;
    break;
    default: System.out.println("cannot compute");
    break;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Can I get help me with the error in my logic?

Comment: Is this homework? If so are you allowed to use binary trees?

Comment: why is your border 5 elements? why not 3 elements as in "1 + 1"?

Comment: @Michael Hobbs this is an exercise, but I'm not sure what that is so I don't know. I don't think it's necessary based on my class level. (CSE 143).

Comment: @Daniel S the length of the string is 5. I did that because although there are 3 tokens, I didn't know how to determine how large the string was besides the .length() method

Comment: Ah, I didn't count the spaces. Are you allowed to rely on the spaces being present?

Comment: @DanielS. Understand. A binary tree is one of the best ways to solve these sorts of problems. The next question now that binary trees are out is how many different symbols are you dealing with? You are going to need to parse your string and dived it up into sub strings based on the symbol set you have.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs are you talking about branching with a switch statement? I will post my code (which does not compile correctly) up to show what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating for more than 3 symbols (not counting spaces), as in "1 + 2 + 3",
you have to calculate in this order: 1 + (2 + 3).

You have to split up the first 1 and the remainig part "2 + 3", and pass the remaining part to the calculate method again. Something like:

```
int firstPart = ...; // evaluation of "1"
int secondPart = calculate("2 + 3");

int total = firstPart + secondPart;
```